How do I install an obsolete Clang?
Our project is built with clang-13 which is not available with APT on Ubuntu 24, looks like it has become obsolete:
sudo apt install clang-13
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package clang-13 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'clang-13' has no installation candidate

I've tried to install a package manually from this debian archive via dpkg, but this results in too many dependencies which do not install automatically. Perhaps, I should add some repository for apt, but I do not know which one.
The same problem is with libraries such as lld-13, libc++-13-dev, libc++abi-13-dev.
Can someone help me solve this problem?

The clang-13 package is available in Ubuntu 22.04. If you really want to use Ubuntu 24.04, you cannot use deb packages. Tarballs are available at https://releases.llvm.org/download.html for you to manually install.

This question is similar to: How do I install clang 18 on Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'll try following the guide provided in the answer, but to me it looks like the linked problem is rather about new clang releases unavailable on older Ubuntu version than about obsolete packages.

@graham As expected, the guide does not work. The repository 'http://apt.llvm.org/noble llvm-toolchain-noble-13 Release' does not have a Release file.
